# Calling list function with Dr Racket R5RS undefined error for '( 1 2 3) for the list

Tags: scheme, racket, r5rs

I have function setup as

(define function (lambda (lst s1 s2 s3) ...... )))

when calling it - (function '(1 2 3) 0 0 0) - I am getting this error because of the ' ? What do I need to add into my code for it to understand the list " 1 2 3 " ? I have # lang racket at the top.. error below

‘: undefined;
 cannot reference an identifier before its definition

Answer (score 1):

It's quite possible that the quote `'` character you're using is incorrect, this happens when you copy-paste code from a source with the wrong fonts. Try copying it again from the code below, it should work:

```
#lang racket

(define function
  (lambda (lst s1 s2 s3)
    'ok))

(function '(1 2 3) 0 0 0)
; => 'ok
```

If that doesn't work, then there's a problem with the actual body of the function, and you should add it to the question.

Comment: @JackCreager if this post solved your problem, please don’t forget to accept it ;) just click on the check mark to its left.